# playPause Button instead of text in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change the play/pause text into Image, but I am struggling to do that. Here is the part of my source code:

HTML:

```
<body>
<button id="audioControl" onclick="Play()">Play</button>
<canvas id="progress" width="500" height="100"></canvas>
<audio id="audio" ontimeupdate="progressBar()" 
  src="horse.mp3">
</audio>
<br>
```

JS:

```
var audioElement = document.getElementById("audio")
var canvas = document.getElementById("progress").getContext('2d')
var audio_ctrl = document.getElementById('audioControl')
function Play() {
var play = audio_ctrl.innerHTML === 'Play'
var method
if (play) {
 audio_ctrl.innerHTML = 'Pause'
method = 'play'
} else {
 audio_ctrl.innerHTML = 'Play'
 method = 'pause'
}
audioElement[method]()
}
```

Can anyone help me to change make this play/pause as an image?

Comment: can you please show your attempt with the image?

Comment: You're editing `innerHTML`. How would you normally write HTML to show an image instead of plain text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to change your button to an other element, style it and do play onclick on it.

Here, I updated/extended your code:

```html
<body>
<button id="audioControl" onclick="Play()">Play</button>
<div id="audioControlImage" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background: url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149668.svg')" onclick="Play()"></div>
<canvas id="progress" width="500" height="100"></canvas>
<audio id="audio" ontimeupdate="progressBar()" 
  src="https://sample-videos.com/audio/mp3/crowd-cheering.mp3">
</audio>
<br>
<script>
var audioElement = document.getElementById("audio")
var canvas = document.getElementById("progress").getContext('2d')
var audio_ctrl = document.getElementById('audioControl')
var audio_ctrl_image = document.getElementById('audioControlImage')

function Play() {
    var play = audio_ctrl.innerHTML === 'Play'
    var method
    if (play) {
        audio_ctrl.innerHTML = 'Pause'
        audio_ctrl_image.style.background = "url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/8/8725.svg')"
        method = 'play'
    } else {
        audio_ctrl.innerHTML = 'Play'
        audio_ctrl_image.style.background = "url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149668.svg')"
        method = 'pause'
    }
    audioElement[method]()
}
</script>
</body>
```